# ¿Cómo visualizar correctamente los datos actualizados de mi tabla en html con js?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Mi inconveniente es el siguiente, he creado una tabla que se va llenando a medida que se van llenando los datos, ahora se debe realizar la edición pero cuando tomo cuaquier item y edito los datos al poner guardar se actualiza unicamente el primer registro de la tabla. A continuación dejo mi código:

html:

```
    <tbody id="tabla_proucto">
    </tbody>
```

js:

**Crear filas en tabla**

```
var elemento = document.createElement("TR");
var boton_eliminar = document.createElement("BUTTON");
var boton_editar = document.createElement("BUTTON");
boton_eliminar.setAttribute("id", "botonEliminar");
fila="<tr>" +"<td id = 'cantidadtabla' disabled >"+producto.Cantidad+"</td>" + 
    "<td id = 'descrip'>"+producto.Descripcion+"</td>" +
    "<td id = 'preciounit'>"+producto.PrecioUnitario+"</td>" +
    "<td id = 'tarifaproduct'>"+tarifaProducto+"</td>" +
    "<td id = 'descuentoproduct'>"+producto.Descuento+"</td>" + 
    "<td id = 'valortotal'>"+valorTotal+"</td>" +
    "<td id = 'iceporproduct'>"+icePorProd+"</td>" +
    "</tr>";

$('#myModalCreate').modal('hide');
elemento.innerHTML=fila;
document.getElementById("tabla_proucto").appendChild(elemento);
boton_eliminar.innerText = 'Eliminar';
boton_editar.innerText = 'Editar';
document.getElementById("tabla_proucto").appendChild(boton_eliminar);
document.getElementById("tabla_proucto").appendChild(boton_editar);
```

**Editar filas en tabla**

```
function editProduct() {
        contEditProduct ++
        arrayRows.indexOf(rowCount)
        $("#myModalEdit").modal("show");    
        document.getElementById("cantidadedit").value  = det.cantidad
        var cpedit = document.getElementById("codPedit").value

        if (cpedit == ""){
            document.getElementById("codPedit").value = ""
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("codPedit").value  = det.codigoPrincipal
        }
        document.getElementById("descripcionedit").value  = det.descripcion
        document.getElementById("precioUnitarioedit").value = det.impuestos[0].impuesto[0].baseImponible
        document.getElementById("descuentoedit").value   = det.descuento
        document.getElementById("rateedit").value = det.impuestos[0].impuesto[0].tarifa
        console.log("detalleList.indexOf(det): " + detalleList.indexOf(det) )

    $scope.editProductView = function(){
        console.log("filas: " + filas)
        console.log("filas.indexOf(fila): " + filas.indexOf(fila))
        console.log("detalle list: " + detalleList)

        var TotalEditar = new Array()

        var tarifaProductoEdit = document.getElementById("rateedit")
        tarifaProductoEdit = tarifaProductoEdit.options[tarifaProductoEdit.selectedIndex].innerText;

        var tarifasEdit = document.getElementById("rateedit").value
        var precioUnitarioedit = document.getElementById("precioUnitarioedit").value
        var cantidadedit = document.getElementById("cantidadedit").value
        var descripcionedit =  document.getElementById("descripcionedit").value
        if (tarifasEdit == 0){
        //0%
            tarifaImpEdit = 0
        }
        else if (tarifasEdit == 2){ 
        //12%
            tarifaImpEdit = 12
        }
        else if (tarifasEdit == 6){ 
        //No Objeto de Impuestos
            tarifaImpEdit = 0
        }
        else if (tarifasEdit == 7){ 
        //Exento de IVA
            tarifaImpEdit = 0
        }
        else{ 
        }

        var valorTotalEdit = parseFloat(precioUnitarioedit) * parseFloat(cantidadedit)
        var descuentoEdit = document.getElementById("descuentoedit").value
        var CodPorICEedit = document.getElementById("codigoPorcentajeICEedit").value
        var TarifaICEedit = document.getElementById("tarifaICEedit").value


        document.getElementById("cantidadtabla").innerHTML  = cantidadedit
        document.getElementById("descrip").innerHTML  = descripcionedit
        document.getElementById("preciounit").innerHTML  = precioUnitarioedit
        document.getElementById("tarifaproduct").innerHTML  = tarifaProductoEdit
        document.getElementById("descuentoproduct").innerHTML  = descuentoEdit
        document.getElementById("valortotal").innerHTML  = valorTotalEdit
        document.getElementById("iceporproduct").innerHTML  = TarifaICEedit
        //TotalEditar.push(tarifasEdit+"-"+valorTotalEdit+"-"+descuentoEdit+"-"+tarifaImpEdit+"-"+CodPorICEedit+"-"+TarifaICEedit)
        ValTotalEditar = tarifasEdit+"-"+valorTotalEdit+"-"+descuentoEdit+"-"+tarifaImpEdit+"-"+CodPorICEedit+"-"+TarifaICEedit + ""
        det.codigoPrincipal = document.getElementById("codPedit").value
        //det.codigoAuxiliar = producto.CodigoAuxiliar;
        det.descripcion = document.getElementById("descripcionedit").value 
        det.cantidad = document.getElementById("cantidadedit").value 
        det.precioUnitario = document.getElementById("precioUnitarioedit").value 
        det.descuento = document.getElementById("descuentoedit").value   
        det.precioTotalSinImpuesto =  parseFloat(det.precioUnitario) * parseFloat(det.cantidad) - parseFloat(det.descuento) + ""
        det.impuestos[0].impuesto[0].baseImponible = document.getElementById("precioUnitarioedit").value
        det.impuestos[0].impuesto[0].valor = parseFloat(det.precioTotalSinImpuesto) * (tarifaImpEdit/100)
        var posicionDetalleList = detalleList.indexOf(det);

        contEditProduct = 0
        $("#myModalEdit").modal("hide");
    }
}
```

El problema posiblemente esté en que todos los campos de las filas tengan el mismo id, como puedo hacer para que se actualice la fila que edité?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: En angular tenés un [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), podés utilizarlo para mostrar toda la tabla con eso.

Comment: @CarmenA aun sigues teniendo el problema?